# What is TOPIC SUBSCRIPTION STATE in Azure Service Bus Subscription?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Can any one please tell me what TOPIC SUBSCRIPTION STATE setting does in Azure service bus subscription and what are the different values Enabled, Disabled and Receive Enabled(Send only).

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code context?

Comment: I am talking about setting which is at the bottom of edit service bus subscription in Azure Management Portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referring to the ability to change the state of a service bus entity.  This was new and added in April 2013.  This allows you to disable a queue without deleting it, or put it into a state that allows you to keep sending to it, but won't allow anything to receive from it.  Somewhat like suspending it without loosing messages, etc.

Here is the Documentation for [EntityStatus Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.entitystatus.aspx) which is what these settings map to.

[Release notes for Service Bus 2.0 (April 2013)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn198643.aspx) hits on this a little, but much description.

For example, you may want to use this to temporarily stop incoming messages on the queue, or temporarily allow new messages to come in, but to stop all consumers from reading from the queue.